# Summation of entries with the same date in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two columns with data (several thousand rows), one with dates and one with duration (time in hh:ss). However, there's multiple records for each day. Is there any way to add these together based on the date and get one entry per day with the summed value?

Below is a picture showing a subset of my Spreadsheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what could be very useful to you would be the `Consolidate` function.

If you click on the `Data` tab on the menu bar, on the mid-right side is a button called consolidate.

[image: Consolidate location]

**Steps to Success:**

1. Select a range beside your existing values, if you photo is the same I would suggest highlighting all of columns C, and D.
2. With the columns highlighted press the `Consolidate` button.
3. Within consolidate choose `Sum` for the function, and highlight the data in columns A, and B for the reference.
4. Make sure to check off `Left column` in `Use Labels In`
5. With dates properly formatted as dates, and times properly formatted as times this should sum all of the times given for a particular date. Test trials were successful.

Let me know if that works for you, commetn if you have any questions.